# Regex match multiple occurrence of a js function between <script.* and </script> tag

Tags: php, regex

I hope that someone can help me... I'm not a regex expert and I'm looking for a solution for handle a text substitution.

I have an HTML code like this:

```
<script>
...something here...
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
...something here...
</script>

...something here...

<script type="text/javascript">
1st occurrence
...something here...
fbq(...something here...)
...something here...
</script>

...something here...

<script type="text/javascript">
2nd occurrence
...something here...
fbq(...something here...)
</script>

...something here...
```

I need to find all string between ' that contains the function fbq. So in my example I need to have:

Group1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//1st occurrence
...something here...
fbq(...something here...)
...something here...
</script>
```

Group2:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
2nd occurrence
...something here...
fbq(...something here...)
</script>
```

And so on if there are more occurrences. I think It will be fine also to have more matches instead of more groups.

Consideration: there can be a lot of `<script` string in my code that doesn't contains 'fbq' function, and I can't be sure how they are positioned and whether in a newline or not.

I've tried many regex code but I cannot find something that works.

I.e. by using

```
(?:^.*)(<script.*fbq.*<\/script>)(?:.*$)
```

or

```
.*(<script.*fbq.*<\/script>).*
```

I can find only the last occurrence of fbq (in my example only 2nd occurrence).

I've tried also to play with groups inclusion but with no luck.

Then I need to use this regex in a PHP code, for doing a substitution using preg_replace

Any suggestion is very welcome

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nonono - use a proper parser (e.g. `DOMDocument`) instead.

Comment: Never used DOMDocument but yes... it seems to be a better solution. I'm looking the docs about that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must parse HTML, find wanted elements and use regexp for element content. Text search in HTML code (from another sources) is very randomly game. Try DOMDocument and DOMXPath

```
        $doc = new \DOMDocument;
        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = 0;
        $doc->strictErrorChecking = 0;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $doc->loadHTML($html);

        $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
        // search all script element as nodeList
        $nodeList = $xpath->query('//script');
        foreach ($nodeList as $node) {

            $node->nodeValue = 'Hello, world!'; // or some text changes,
            // but remember that comments are special nodes in DOM
            $node->parentNode->replaceChild($node, $node);
        }

        print $doc->saveHTML();
```

Comment: You could use something like `//script[contains(., "fbq")]` to say the script tag must contain the text `fbq`

Comment: @NigelRen thansk, I confirm that it works fine alsow with the contains addition!

Comment: @Pavel Musil do you know if it's possible to change also the <script *> tag?

i.e. I need that <script> or <script type="text/javascript"> became <script  type="text/plain" class="_iub_cs_activate-inline">

(I'm not crazy... it's due to manage cookie consent)

Comment: @Fabio  - sure, simply use `$node->setAttribute('attr_name', 'attr_value');`.

Comment: @PavelMusil thanks! I was trying by changing $node->nodeName but it wasn't the right way ;-)

Thanks a lot for helping me and providing a such useful solution!

Comment: If you want create new element, then use `$newNode = $doc->createElement('element_name', 'element_text_value'); ` and with `replaceChild` put it to dom structure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can be useful for someone in future, this is my final code:

```
function fix_iubenda_pixelWoocommerce( $buffer ) {
        $doc = new \DOMDocument;
        $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = 0;
        $doc->strictErrorChecking = 0;
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $doc->loadHTML($buffer);

        $xpath = new \DOMXPath($doc);
        $nodeList = $xpath->query('//script[contains(., "fbq(")]');
        foreach ($nodeList as $node) {
                $node->nodeValue = $node->nodeValue ;
                $node->setAttribute('type', 'text/plain');
                $node->setAttribute('class', '_iub_cs_activate-inline');
        }

        $buffer = $doc->saveHTML();
        return $buffer;
}
```

Thanks again to Pavel and Nigel for helping me!